# Drupal 8 class not found

Tags: drupal

I know this is no doubt a simple answer, but I just cannot seem to find the answer. I'm following a course online and this is the custom Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\dino_roar\Controller;

use Drupal\dino_roar\Jurrasic\RoarGenerator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RoarController
{
    public function roar($count)
    {
        $test = new RoarGenerator();

        return new Response('hello');

    }
}
```

This is the object:

```
<?php


namespace Drupal\dino_roar\Jurrasic;

class RoarGenerator
{
    public function getRoar($length)
    {
        return 'R' . str_repeat('O', $length) . 'AAARRR';
    }
}
```

But, I keep getting this:

Fatal error: Class 'Drupal\dino_roar\Jurrasic\RoarGenerator' not found

Does anybody have any ideas?

Also, I know Jurassic is spelt wrong :S